# Google Cloud Platform Load Balancer with Apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, mod-proxy

I am trying to configure httpd mod_proxy to serve as a reverse proxy in Google Cloud Platform. I set up a TCP load balancer and tried something like this in a VM apache config.

```
<Proxy "*">
</Proxy>

Listen 7001
Listen 7002

<VirtualHost *:7001>
ProxySourceAddress <LB IP 1 here>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:7002>
ProxySourceAddress <LB IP 2 here>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache logs show my attempts to GET through to yandex.ru via proxy:

```
 AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.yandex.ru
 (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 5.255.255.5:80 (*) failed
```

httpd version 2.4.6. OS Centos 7.

What am I missing here?